# Spring webflow + CDI

Tags: java, cdi, spring-webflow

Are Spring Webflow and CDI compatible?
I'm having problems deploying the application with beans.xml(CDI) included.

I'm deploying on Jboss 7.1

If I run the application including /WEB-INF/beans.xml (CDI) I have this exception :

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletExceptio n: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutio nException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'modalidades' of flow 'comprar'
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.p
>   rocessRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.d
>   oGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet .java:734)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet .java:847)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 343)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.
>   FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInt erceptor.java:109)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.
>   FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityI nterceptor.java:83)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionT
>   ranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilt er.java:97)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionMa
>   nagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.ja va:100)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.An
>   onymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuth
>   enticationFilter.java:78)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.Securi
>   tyContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(Securit
>   yContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.Requ
>   estCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilt er.java:35)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.http://www.BasicAuthenticationFilter...lter.java:177)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Ab
>   stractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(Abst
>   ractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.lo
>   gout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityC
>   ontextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPe
>   rsistenceFilter.java:79)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
>   VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java: 355)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.
>   doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterPro
>   xy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterPro
>   xy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilt
>   er.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) root cause
>
> org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutio nException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'modalidades' of flow 'comprar'
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecut
>   ionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:571)
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecut
>   ionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:262)
>   org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorI
>   mpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandle
>   rAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>   org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAd
>   apter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
>   doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
>   doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.p
>   rocessRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>
> javax.faces.FacesException: Error Checking Last Modified for
>   jndi:/default-host/webflow-primefaces-showcase/modalidades.xhtml
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache._g
>   etLastModified(DefaultFaceletCache.java:175)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.ac
>   cess$000(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.
>   newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:93)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.
>   newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:89)
>   com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(
>   ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Futu reTask.java:334)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.jav a:166)
>   com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(Exp
>   iringConcurrentCache.java:114)
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException
>   org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnectio
>   n.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:369)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache._g
>   etLastModified(DefaultFaceletCache.java:172)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.ac
>   cess$000(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.
>   newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:93)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.
>   newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:89)
>   com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(
>   ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)

When I remove beans.xml, the application works fine.

Comment: What problems are you having and where are you deploying? Tomcat? WebSphere? Maybe you should post some logs...

Comment: And: No, they are not supposed to be compatible. But more information will help :)

Answer (score 0):

They don't interoperate out of the box, but you can use something like http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SpringModule to bridge them.

However, the issue in case project seems to be JSF-related (and CDI just causes it to show up). I suspect that Spring Webflow's JSF handling is clashing with the JSF servlet, but can't be sure until this is reproduced.

It would be great if you could provide a way to reproduce this (i.e. do you see it with one of the sample applications?)

Comment: You can reproduce the error adding CDI to this sample application :
svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/webflow-primefaces-showcase
Thanks !